# Ext JS 4 - not focus combo box when you select the fieldLabel

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, extjs4.1

We have a basic combo box

http://www.samuellevy.com/blog/2010/10/senchaextjs-combo-box-gotchas-and-how-fix-them

we don't want that the fieldLabel when you click it , the focus go to the combobox

Any one can help me thank you !

Comment: Just curious, why? I think it will be very confusing for the user...

Answer (score 1):

Add this listener to your Combo config:

```
xtype: 'combo',
id: 'myCombo',
listeners: {
    render: function(obj) {
        Ext.get(obj.id+'-labelEl').on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```